# Is there equivalent to PHP's addslashes in Perl?

Tags: perl

PHP addslashes:

> string addslashes ( string $str )
>
> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be quoted in 
>   database queries etc. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("),
>   backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).
>
> An example use of addslashes() is when you're entering data into a database. 
>   For example, to insert the name O'reilly into a database, you will need to 
>   escape it. It's highly recommended to use DBMS specific escape function (e.g. 
>   mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL or pg_escape_string() for PostgreSQL), 
>   but if the DBMS you're using doesn't have an escape function and the DBMS 
>   uses \ to escape special chars, you can use this function. This would only be
>   to get the data into the database, the extra \ will not be inserted. Having 
>   the PHP directive magic_quotes_sybase set to on will mean ' is instead escaped
>   with another '.

Is there equivalent to PHP's addslashes in Perl?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is there equivalent to PHP's addslashes in Perl?

Yeah. But you don't want to do that.

If you're executing database queries, the only proper way to deal with dynamic parameters is to use [DBI placeholders](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values). These will result in your parameters being sent separately from the query (or properly serialized within the query if your database does not support parameterized queries.)

Comment: I am a newbie, searching answer for the same question.could you please give a little simple example for this answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.